# Is there a difference between "brainstorming" and "mindstorming"?

Tags: differences, nouns, errors

Some people use *brainstorming*, others use *mindstorming*. I could not find the difference between the two words.

Comment: The [LEGO **Mindstorm** series of kits contain software and hardware to create small, customizable and programmable robots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Mindstorms) - but the word seems to have no currency apart from that, so I think this question is Too Localised

Answer (score 6):

*Mindstorming* [doesn't appear in the most common dictionaries](http://www.onelook.com/?w=mindstorming&ls=a&loc=2osdf).

Aside from the fact that *mindstorming* is uncommon to the point of invisibility, its meaning is fairly clear, especially in the context of brainstorming. But the difference is that it's never used, or as good as never used.

Consequently, if you have a choice, use *brainstorming*.

Answer (score 3):

"Brainstorming" is a commonly used and commonly accepted word. "Mindstorming" is not. As far as I can tell it means the same as "brainstorming", and thus it is difficult to see why we need a new word to express an idea that we already have a word for. (IMHO it's just an effort by some people to sound like they're introducing a new idea when they're just recycling the same old ideas, but that may be getting off topic.)

Comment: I think "mindstorming" is a variant of "brainstorming", but since it is not a well-known word, it can mean whatever you want it to mean.  I guess when a buisiness-helping guru comes up with a variant of the traditional brainstorm process, he may give it a new name, like "mindstorming".

Comment: Thank you Jay and Andrew, I remember that Brian Tracy used "Mindstorming" in one of his books. I guess that he means that Brainstorming can mostly occur between a group of people, but Mindstorming can be by someone trying to generate ideas by his own.

Comment: @RamiAl-Muhtaseb Yeah, I vaguely recall reading the term "mindstorming" many years ago only in the context of a specific product that was being advertised.